# how to remove result set from html page

Tags: mysql, html, perl

I have a MySQL database, and few perl scripts using which i am generating the webpages.

On Html page links are available,

For example-

Customer_link  => (calls customers.pl) query executed - select * from customers.

Now there is one more link say Customer_in_mumbai => it should remove all the customers whose city is not mumbai.

How to achieve that?
do i need to execute the query once again with where clause or any other way is also possible so that i can simply remove the customers whose city is not mumbai?

Also if i need to execute the query again, do i need to write one more perl file, if not how can i use the same file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to manipulate on the client side of things after it's been loaded/displayed. There's nothing you can do on the server side to change a page once it's been downloaded without Javascript.

The rest of your questions indicate a lack of familiary with how dynamic web pages are generated. You can have a single page that does all that, using standard HTTP query variables to modify how the script operates. e.g.

```
http://example.com/yourscript.pl?remove=mumbai
```

then have Perl retrieve that `remove` value and use it to modify how the database query runs. But showing you that is beyond the scope of this site - we're not here to teach you, just help fix problems.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems you only want to remove it from the page temporarily for the user. You can achieve that simply by remove rows with mumbai as a value with Javascript. That should save you server side processing. Use a Library like JQuery to achieve it easily.